# Is it possible to check that class has static block (via reflection or other ways)?

Tags: java, reflection, static

Is it possible to check that class has static block ?

For example to check that class has static fields reflection can be used by calling `clazz.getDeclaredFields()` and then iterate it to found static field.

With static methods the same - `clazz.getDeclaredMethods()`

But `getDeclaredMethods` doesn't return methods for `init` and `clinit`.  Is there are any other way to check that class have static initialization block?

Comment: If you're using reflection it is not possible to avoid the execution of these blocks as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663302/java-static-initializers-and-reflection)

Comment: Actually I'm taking class from parent classloader and can inspect him, and, if it match my condition (has static's) I load this class with current classLoader

Comment: For what testing purposes? Why are you testing things that cannot happen?

Comment: guys please concentrate on question in topic.

Comment: about testing - I do functional testing of my daemon program. Lets imagine I call it to times, so in prod each time it starts in new jvm. For testing I don't want to start many jvms, I can just reload classes where I have to refresh static fields.  BUT it should not touch you, because my question is about how to check that class has static initializer, and nothing else

Comment: The relevance of that information still is entirely unclear. Reloading implies executing the static blocks, *if* you are truly reloading, which doesn’t seem so, as your description of how you use the parent classloader contradicts it.

Comment: the short answer is `no`, the long answer is `no and if you are trying to do this your code base stinks to high heaven` as well now that I think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code.

```
 public static boolean check(Class<?> cls) {
    try {
        Method method = ObjectStreamClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("hasStaticInitializer", Class.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return (boolean) method.invoke(null, cls);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
    }
    // trivial
    throw new RuntimeException();
}

static class Test { static { } }
static class Test2 { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    assert check(Test.class);
    assert !check(Test2.class);
}
```

Comment: I see this method marked private and also is undocumented, but anyway nice solution.

Comment: If you read and understood [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44286447/2711488), you made test cases like `static class Test { static String S = "1"; }` or `static class Test { Test() { assert "A".hashCode()==65; } }` or even `enum Test { }`, but of course, that’s quiet uncomfortable as they prove that my answer still holds, there is no way to distinguish between a class with a static initializer and a class having a `static` field with an initializer, or a class having an `assert` statement somewhere or just an `enum`, which appears to have an initializer even when being entirely empty.

Comment: @nahab please cancel selecting best answer.

Comment: guys, if I could mark two answers I would do. This solution is a bit undocumented and have many underwater rocks, but it exists, thus I will stay with this one.

Comment: Hacky but does exactly what is asked in the original question and what I was looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to test for the presence of `static` initializers, as that information isn’t even available at byte code level. In a class file, there might be a single initialization method, `<clinit>`, whose existence might be caused by the existence of `static` field initializers, `static` initialization blocks, or the mere presence of an `assert` statement somewhere in that class, to name some possible reasons. Of course, there could be more than one reason, including reasons not mentioned here. Since that bytecode artifact has no language semantic, there is no Reflection method to test for its presence.

However, if a class has no mutable `static` fields, there is nothing to manipulate by a `static` initializer, that could make a difference between a “fresh class” and a class state that is not “fresh”. While initializers could have side effects, these could not alter the class, if there are no `static` fields to change. But if the initializer is manipulating the state of other classes, you get initialization order dependency issues anyway.

Also, the idea to reload a single class because of fulfilling certain criteria, without reloading the others, which interact with that class, doesn’t work at all, as these old classes will also stay linked as they are, not using the newly loaded class version.

The simplest (if not only) solution is to reload all classes of a particular class loader, to get a fresh new state. Trying to selectively reload some classes only, is just an optimization attempt, but there is no point in trying to optimize a *testing* environment…

Comment: you're right - I make optimisation. Our tests runs 20 mins, so even such small optimization can be good, as it gives few additional minutes. But you point about linking between classes make me return back and think to reload all classes :)  Thanks for such wide general explanation, that is really what I want to hear as explanation.    And. I tried to do this because in our production codebase we have some bad designed classes (not mine) with such fields that I don't want to touch.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do what you are wanting to do because that is not how things work. Even if you could it is a terrible idea and means you have a fundamental flaw in your design of your system.

[**Static Initialization Blocks**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

> A static initialization block is a normal block of code enclosed in
>   braces, { }, and preceded by the static keyword. Here is an example:

```
static {
    // whatever code is needed for initialization goes here
}
```

> A class can have any number of static initialization blocks, and they
>   can appear anywhere in the class body. The runtime system guarantees
>   that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they
>   appear in the source code.
>
> There is an alternative to static blocks — you can write a private
>   static method:

```
class Whatever {
    public static varType myVar = initializeClassVariable();

    private static varType initializeClassVariable() {

        // initialization code goes here
    }
}
```

> The advantage of private static methods is that they can be reused
>   later if you need to reinitialize the class variable.